# User input number dialog box in flutter

Tags: android, ios, list, flutter, dart

I'm a new flutter user. I'm trying to make a shopping list app. Basically the first page contains 3 clickable images. These images are the logos of the three stores we currently shop at for our supplies. When you click on the image, it takes you to another page that has a grid view of all of the items (pictures of the items) that we purchase from that store. My end goal is that when you click on the picture of the item, a dialog box pops up asking how many of this item you would like to put on the list, then put it on the list. I've gotten as far as creating a grid view of the items, and making the first image clickable, but I'm not sure how to make the input dialog box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Shopping List');
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Pick a store to start your list"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 150, maxWidth: 150),
                  child: Ink.image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/aldi.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 150, maxWidth: 150),
                  child: Ink.image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/rd.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 150, maxWidth: 150),
                  child: Ink.image(
                    image: AssetImage('images/sams.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => FourthRoute()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Aldi's"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(onPressed: (),
                child: Image.asset('images/2milk.jpg'),
              ),
              Image.asset('images/skimMilk.jpg'),
              Image.asset('images/almondMilk.jpg'),
              Image.asset('images/coconutMilk.jpg'),
              Image.asset('images/soyMilk.jpg'),
              Image.asset('images/halfAndHalf.jpg'),
              Image.asset('images/heavyCream.jpg'),
              Image.asset('images/whipCream.jpg'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Restraurant Depot"),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}

class FourthRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sam's Club"),
      ),
      body: Center(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To make a dialog box, there are many widgets you can use. 
I think the best use case here is an `AlertDialog` with your widgets items like `TextField` on top.

Inside the onTap add this, you can leave the long decorations if you don't want a frame-less border, i just added them to make my `TextField` look neater. You can also leave the controller, if you do not plan using a `TextEditingController`.

```
onTap: () {
var alert = AlertDialog(
  title: Text("How many items do you need?"),
  content: TextField(
    style: TextStyle(
      decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    maxLines: 1,
    maxLengthEnforced: false,
    autofocus: false,
    enabled: true,
    onSubmitted: (String text) {
      int number_input = int.parse(text);
      // Do something with your number like pass it to the next material page route
},
    controller: _controller,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
    border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
    disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 40, 40, 1.0),),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
      prefixIcon: new Icon(
        Icons.playlist_add,
        size: 18.0,),),),);

showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
   return alert;
  },);
},
```

Comment: If it worked, don't forget to upvote this answer and mark it as the accepted solution by clicking that check mark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add You Trigger **OnTap()**  on your image and then use this code to pop your Custom dialog by create your widget in Container

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => Container(
          child: //add you custom widget here

        ));
```